# How should user data be updated globally and then displayed in react native when it changes

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to allow users to update their settings in my app. I've sent the new settings that the user has chosen to the database to be saved and that works, but then the user's new info isn't being updated in my app. Would I be better sending a request for the users info to be updated in my AuthContext everytime the user's data changes, as this can then be passed down to all of my other screens, or is there another way to do it better, I know I could make a new request to the database every time a new page is opened, but this seems slow and inefficient.

Sorry I haven't provided any code, but I don't think it will help with my question, as I'm just making a fetch request to save the new user data to the database, then I need a way for this new user data to be updated globally. I'm currently requesting the user data on my app.js page when the user first opens the app and then passing this down to all the other pages using AuthContext, which is why it doesn't automatically update user data when it changes.

Comment: There are a many alternatives. You should look at Apollo GraphQL (if you are using graphql), redux is a common library and AuthContext is also an option. Ultimately the implementation decision is yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store the user data at the app level we can use the Context API or React-Redux.
We also can use Async Storage to save the user data in the app-data in the device.

Check out the example to implement **Context API**

https://blog.logrocket.com/a-deep-dive-into-react-context-api/

Check out the below for **Redux implementation**

https://react-redux.js.org/

Check out the docs for **Async Storage**:

https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/install/